# Does anyone know of a D20 system that uses the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: game-recommendation, roleplaying, d20-system

Does anyone know of a D20 system that uses the Harry Potter Universe?

I want to try something new with a few of my friends. We really want to try and get away from the usual D&D for a bit and try to use the Harry Potter universe as a start. I could just build something from scratch based on our knowledge of Harry Potter and those sources (i.e. books, movies, comics, etc.) but I would really appreciate a good starting point as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3929/760

Comment: Not d20, so not an actual answer, but related enough to mention - a Harry Potter-esque RPG ... looks like it's still in playtest, and that it focuses on narrating the experiences of kids in a wizarding school: http://atthetablegames.com/?cat=4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After Googling, I found this:

[Broomstix, the unofficial Harry Potter RolePlaying Game](http://www.memento-mori.com/other/games/broomstix_rpg.pdf) and [Character Sheet](http://www.memento-mori.com/other/games/broomstix_cs.pdf), which is distributed for free.

[Source.](http://www.memento-mori.com/other/games/)

And this is [some people discussing the idea of a HP RPG.](http://blog.retroroleplaying.com/2009/07/simple-tabletop-rpg-for-harry-potter.html)